# Grid Template Areas not working using SASS

Tags: html, css, sass

Hi I've been trying to do this grind layout but it Grid template areas not working. As by code I want to implement it in two rows with 6 columns

```css
#about-a .about-info {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "bioimage bio bio" "aw1 aw2 aw3";
  grid-gap: 1.2rem;
}

#about-a .bio-image {
  grid-area: bioimage;
}

#about-a .bio {
  grid-area: bio;
  border: 3px solid #a862ea;
  padding: 0.8rem;
}

#about-a .award-1 {
  grid-area: aw1;
}

#about-a .award-2 {
  grid-area: aw2;
}

#about-a .award-3 {
  grid-area: aw3;
}

#about-a .award-1 .fas,
#about-a .award-2 .fas,
#about-a .award-3 .fas {
  color: #a862ea;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<section id="about-a" class="text-center py-2">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="section-title">About Me</h2>
    <div class="bottom-line"></div>
    <p class="lead">A little about me and what I do..</p>
    <div class="about-info">
      <img src="image/about_new.jpg" alt="" class="bio-image">
      <div class="bio bg-light">
        <h4>All of my projects can be found on github..</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum, aspernatur enter code hereratione quia natus iure maxime corporis nemo exercitationem harum, inventore voluptate quis nisi commodi dolorum velit laudantium eum. Excepturi, autem!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="award-1">
        <i class="fas fa-award fa-3x"></i>
        <h3>Award One</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio, fugit.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="award-2">
        <i class="fas fa-award fa-3x"></i>
        <h3>Award Two</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio, fugit.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="award-3">
        <i class="fas fa-award fa-3x"></i>
        <h3>Award Three</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio, fugit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

using dev tools the layout is appearing in singe row as shown below rather than as implemented in CSS and the original defined layout is striked through.

```
grid-template-areas:
        "bioimage" 
        "bio" 
        "bio"
        "aw1" 
        "aw2" 
        "aw3";
```

Comment: Please show the compiled CSS instead of SCSS code, and turn your code into a runnable snippet here. To achieve that, click "edit" below your post, then click on the icon that resembles `<>`.

Comment: Hey try using a grid visualiser tool like`https://grid.layoutit.com`

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `grid-template-colums:` element.

Solution:

```
#about-a .about-info {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "bioimage bio bio" "aw1 aw2 aw3";
  grid-gap: 1.2rem;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 300px //for instance
}
```

If this doesn't work, feel free to comment down here.

Comment: nope did not work.

Comment: You tried it with 3 items like: `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;`?

Comment: The weird thing is that the demo is working like it should right. So I don't get the problem

Comment: I want something like this `image bio bio` also note that bio is one element and I want to take it two columns. Yea weirdly it is working fine in demo but when I try to launch it through local host seems like grid is not even applying.

Comment: Thats weird, maybe check out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas